# What is the pot split in this scenario?

Tags: texas-hold-em, side-pots

I'm trying to understand as many pot scenarios as I can, and this one is troubling me.

[image: Pot]

Can someone explain to me what would happen in this scenario?

If needed, increase the bet amount of Player 7 so they have bet high enough that they'll get some of their money back (I could have set it at 100, but the graph would have looked silly).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew's answer is correct, and is an example of the bottom-up approach typically taught to casino dealers.  Another way to look at it is top-down from the highest bet (sometimes this is easier for a computer):

1. Nobody matched player 7's last $3, so he is refunded those.
2. At the $4 - $7 level, players 1..3 split $13: $3 from each of them, $1 from player 5, and $3 from player 7.
3. All remaining $28 is split among players 1..4.
4. Players 5,6,8,9 get nothing, because all of their bets are covered by players with better hands.

Comment: That's such a relief, because that's how I coded it! Thank you so much for your response. I'll accept this is the answer as you wrote it in a computer-programmer's-mind way :)

Answer (score 1):

Players 1-3 stand to win up to 7, while Player 4 stands only to win up to 4.

Player 7 will be returned 3 since only 7 is required to call the all-in.

The main pot (28) will be split between Players 1-4.  The side pot (13) will be split between Players 1-3.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I've accepted the other answer as it was framed in a way that made it easier for me to understand. I really appreciate your time!